# Sharepoint 2010: List vs. Subsite for multi-level navigation

Tags: sharepoint

I'm setting up a public-facing website with 4 levels of navigation. There is a fixed top level navigation that breaks things into section. The second level of navigation is a horizontal menu. The 3rd and 4th levels are displayed in a tree menu.

Should this be set up in lists, or in subsites? I understand that you can nest folders inside other lists, so I'm not sure how you'd go about handling this navigation.

When should you use a subsite instead of a list?

The look/feel of all top level sections is the same.

I'm new to this Sharepoint stuff, so I'd like to know some best practices. Thanks!

**Edit: Site Structure**

There is a fixed horizontal top-level navigation. Each of these links points to a landing page for that section.

Each top-level section has it's own sub navigation. This is a horizontal single level navigation.

Pages within that 2nd level could have sub-pages displayed in a two-level tree style. The 3rd level would be clickable with it's own landing page, so it's not just a 'folder' or container. So, that makes four levels of navigation.

**Vent**

This kind of information architecture should be very straightforward to set up in any content management product, but SharePoint is just not intuitive to me at all. I find that documentation on creating public facing custom designed sites to be extremely lacking.

Comment: You can't really nest a list within another list - you can create folders and group by metadata, but no lists within lists. Typically I use Lists/Libraries at the lowest level of my taxonomies.

Comment: So subsites is the only real way to accomplish multi-level navigation? (with lists being the last level)

Comment: I think this problem is a good illustration of why SharePoint shouldn't be considered as a general purpose web content management system. Ultimately it has a small set of containers, whose behaviour and degree of nestability are fairly fixed, and can't necessarily be fitted to any arbitrary information architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends - A list and a site hold very different content. Your navigation shouldn't dictate your content. It should be the other way around. A list describes related items, whereas a site is a container for many lists, document libraries, etc.

Comment: Ok, so do you have advice on which approach to take? In further experimenting I see that you can create a folder inside a list, and add items inside that. however, this makes authoring a bit of a pain as you'd have to manually move new items inside those folders or use content organizer. Plus, I can't seem to figure out how to give a folder a title that's different than the url. I tried using a Sharepoint:SPTreeView against a SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl but it just displays the folders as their url.

Comment: It all completely depends on what 'stuff' you want to appear at the end of your navigation. Right now (probably just due to a lack of understanding on my part) it sounds as though you're building a navigational structure just for the sake of building navigational structure. Are you going to be showing a specific list with specific information at the end of the breadcrumb, or a place with many lists and many libraries? The former is a list, and the latter is a subsite.

Comment: The navigation structure comes from the site map (information architecture) and the design comps. I'm building it because it's dictated to me. I'm just trying to organize public facing content pages in a flexible way.

Comment: Try Root Site (Site Collection) -> Subsite (Of any template) -> Publishing Site.

The publishing site will contain 'Pages' that represent your 4th-level nodes/content pages

Comment: Thanks. Would the 3rd level (nodes) be a subsite as well?

Comment: Yes, they would be a subsite.

Comment: FYI - subsites is working fine in our scenario. Seems to make sense for publishing sites.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution for a custom navigation in Sharepoint 2010 utilizing their built in aspmenu.

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/